# Ctrl button 'sticks' in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

For three weeks now I have this problem that drives my insanity up - and my productivity down: 
Whenever I hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button, my computer keyboard behaves as if I the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button were pressed all the time:

- rolling mouse wheel will increase-decrease zoom of active window
- [P] will open printing dialogue window,
- [s] will open dialogue box to save...

I can reset the computer to normal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd>, but I have to do it every minute or so.
Here is what I did so far:

   I bought a new keyboard, but did not change the problem which seems to be related to Windows
   I uninstalled the keyboard and mouse completely in device manager, then did a reboot to reinstall.
   I deactivated all checkboxes in Ease of Access completely, but to no avail.
   With @Peter we looked into sticky keys and deactivated those – problem persists

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: By any chance, do you have AutoHotkey installed?

Comment: @jjk_charles No AutoHotkey installed (I checked with Windows 7 SEARCH)

Answer (score -1):

This issue is caused by a Chinoy keyboard application which is embedded in a program called HP USB Smartcard application.
Right click start menu, Go into control panel, (make sure it's on classic view) on programs click on uninstall a program, look for the above (HP USB Smartcard application), right click it and uninstall it.
Re-start your PC and that should cure it.
Reply   

Comment: The question doesn't mention anything about an HP USB Smartcard application or a Chinoy keyboard application. There are any number of things that could cause this behaviour.